# map not showing data points on the first time access. Swift3 xcode7

Tags: swift, maps

My map is not showing data points on the first time accessing the app.

1) viewcontroller1 gets the user's location authorisation
2) viewcontroller1 fetches data (for map points) when the user clicks a 'fetch data' button.  It fetches data from Realm (lat long etc) for the data classes. In my console I can see it successfully returns the lat/longs.
3) on the 'fetch data' button press, viewcontroller1 segues to a Mapview controller to show the mapped data.

My problem is that the first time using the app, there is no data points mapped. With no changes - if they return to the viewcontroller1 and retry on 'take 2' the data points appear on the maps. But never the first time Why could this be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what exactly has caused this- but I presume the issue is that the map is loading faster than the data is loading. Here's a solution that's fixed the problem: Instead of the button going directly to the map, I've slowed down the process so that it gives more time for the data to process into the Realm, by adding in an alert to let the user know the "data" is fetched, with an "ok" to close the alert. When the user hits "ok" on the alert, it segues to my map. And now the data shows.